# How to Redirect to another action from ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this simple view where when i clicked a button it send some data to another action through ajax call and should open another view.

```
  public ActionResult ExtesibleCosting(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Trn_IOU ous = new Trn_IOU();

        ous = db.Trn_IOU.Find(Convert.ToInt16(param1));

        ous.Trn_Items =(from p in db.Trn_Items
                                 where p.IOU_DOC_NO == param2
                                 select p).ToList(); 

        return View(ous);
    }
```

but its not working.

passing parameters with ajax call works fine.
Linq Query works fine.
returning data and model objects are fine.
even the debugger also jump to the page and goes through elements.
opening the view directly from a link works fine.
return redirect to action also not working. 
Chrome debuging under network XHR also shows the view name  but TTFB shows waiting .
No page errors or console erros displaying.

Any Idea on this matter. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Do not use ajax if you want to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want AJAX to do your operation but wants to redirect, you can use this code:

```
success: function(result) {
  if (result == true) {
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")';
   } elseif {
      //Do other logics
   }
}
```

This will redirect you on success call on your AJAX. Or whatever link you want to specify.

Change your return type to Json on your ActionResult:

```
return Json(new { isSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I tried this with your code but didnt work  . if i dont put post or get no data would post. any alternative way ?  
$.ajax({                type: "POST",
                            url: "/Trn_IOU/ExtesibleCosting",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ param1: a, param2: b }),
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                windows.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExtesibleCosting", "POPM_Trn_IOU")';                          
                            }

Comment: I forgot to tell you to edit your return. Replace your return View(ous); to return Json as specified on my new edited answer.

Comment: Thanks I got it through .  but return json doesnt needed. i just passed the variables and returned the view and it worked.  perevioulsy i misspelled window to windows :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that it's through an ajax call. Fetching the contents of a view via ajax will not automatically change your page to be looking at the view.

If you want to make a button press result in a new page, you should make the button act as a link.

In your .cshtml file:

```
<a class="looksLikeAButton" href="./ExtensibleCosting?param1=value1&param2=value2">Click me</a>
```

If the parameter values are determined after page load (ie through scripts triggered by user actions), then your javascript should programatically change the url during the lifetime of the page.

Another way of doing this:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("ExtensibleCosting", "MyController")' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="changeThisValueProgramatically" />
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="changeThisAlso" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I got through :)